# Subtract SUM from SUM sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to get the sum of two columns and subtract the second column from the first (both are positive values.)

```
public int getSum(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM (" + KEY_CREDIT + ") - SUM (" + KEY_DEBIT + ") AS myTotal FROM " + TABLE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            sum = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("myTotal"));
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

for some reason its returning 0 even though theres data in the the Credit column for sure.  Right now it should be 27 - 0 = 27

If i run it as

```
// GET SUM
    public int getSum(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM (" + KEY_CREDIT + ") FROM " + TABLE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            sum = c.getInt(0);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

it returns 27 just fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: wouldn't `sum(" + KEY_CREDIT + "-" + KEY_DEBIT + ")"` work

Comment: still seems to return 0

Comment: What happens if you use `sum = c.getInt(0);` even in your first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
// GET SUM
    public int getSum(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(credit), SUM(debit) FROM " + TABLE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            sum = (c.getInt(0) - c.getInt(1));
        }
        return sum;
    }
```